# Migrating Android Studio Project to Desktop Application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin

My question is very simple. Is there a straight forward way to migrate an Android Studio project, which uses Bluetooth, to a Desktop application project (Windows or Linux)?

Comment: Bluestacks?  Otherwise, find a cross platform framework to rewrite everything.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Totally different OSes, different APIs for everything.  YOu can keep some business logic, but anything referencing UIs or hardware will be a total rewrite.